# Changing background color of Kendo/Angular rich editor

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/1ZO8exEm1AOQg3jnvojL?p=preview) I'm trying to change the background color of a KendoEditor widget (see API reference [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/editor#fields-body)). Still, the background color does not change. What's wrong with this code?

HTML

```
  <div class="box">
     <textarea kendo-editor="editor" ng-model="text"></textarea>
  </div>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module("app", [ "kendo.directives" ]);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.$on("kendoWidgetCreated", function(event, widget){
          if (widget === $scope.editor) {
                  $scope.editor.body.style.backgroundColor = "#f00";
                  $scope.editor.refresh();
              }
          });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you refresh it, try to remove `$scope.editor.refresh();`. Works fine when i tried on your plunk

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this : 
Give id say, 'editor' to textarea, fetch its data and then apply style

var editor = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor");
editor.body.style.backgroundColor = "#f00";

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using jQuery and stick with Angular. I know the jQuery statement works.